# Append unique values in json

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have below list;

```
[
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/1",
    "author": "john",
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/2",
    "author": "marry",
    "count": 19
  },
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/1",
    "author": "john",
    "count": 45
  },
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/5",
    "author": "jane",
    "count": 34
  }
]
```

I am trying to append this list into a json file but i only want to append unique values. As you can see my first and third item have exact same title, url and author. Only difference is count. I would like to append only one of these two item regardless of their count number. Append first then ignore others if title, url and author is same. Final json file will be sorted by descending order of count.

I tried below code but it's still appending non-unique values.

```
newlist=[]
[newlist.append(x) for x in originallist if x not in newlist] 
newlist = sorted(newlist, key=lambda k: k.get('count', 0), reverse=True)

ofile = "final.json"

with open(ofile, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(newlist, outfile,indent=2)
```

My final json file should look like below. Sorted by count number and only unique values inserted.

```
[
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/5",
    "author": "jane",
    "count": 34
  },
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/2",
    "author": "marry",
    "count": 19
  },
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/1",
    "author": "john",
    "count": 7
  }
]
```

Any idea what i am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temporary dictionary with a tuple key that consists of the fields you want to check for uniqueness, for example:

```
originallist = [
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/1",
    "author": "john",
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/2",
    "author": "marry",
    "count": 19
  },
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/1",
    "author": "john",
    "count": 45
  },
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/5",
    "author": "jane",
    "count": 34
  }
]

unique_dict = {(d["title"], d["url"], d["author"]): d for d in originallist}
newlist = list(unique_dict.values())
```

The variable `newlist` should now contain the 3 unique dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

*Any idea what i am missing here?*
This:

```
[newlist.append(x) for x in originallist if x not in newlist]
```

does see dictionary as different if any value differ - so treats dicts with different `"count"`s as different.
For me your task looks like task for unique everseen from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). Just do:

```
from itertools import filterfalse
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

then:

```
original_list = [
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/1",
    "author": "john",
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/2",
    "author": "marry",
    "count": 19
  },
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/1",
    "author": "john",
    "count": 45
  },
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/5",
    "author": "jane",
    "count": 34
  }
]
unique_list = list(unique_everseen(original_list, lambda x:(x['title'],x['url'],x['author'])))
print(unique_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'title': 'title1', 'url': 'https://myurl/entry/1', 'author': 'john', 'count': 5}, {'title': 'title1', 'url': 'https://myurl/entry/2', 'author': 'marry', 'count': 19}, {'title': 'title2', 'url': 'https://myurl/entry/5', 'author': 'jane', 'count': 34}]
```

Note that I used `lambda x:(x['title'],x['url'],x['author'])` thus saying *consider two elements same if values of title, url, author are same*, note that this solution assumes that all elements of your list do have `title`, `url` and `author`.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as @Selcuk, but since you asked for the behavior:

> Append first then ignore others if title, url and author is same.

with a slight modification. @Seulcuk's solution would *update* the `unique_dict` elements instead of keeping the original. In your case this mean the `count` element will be updated to the latter ones in the `originallist`. (the `title1` with `https://myurl/entry/1` becomes `count = 45` ) By simply reversing the `originallist` in the iteration this update would equal to keeping the first then ignore. By reversing the list the final `newlist` will have `count = 5` instead of `count = 45`.

edit: feedback from @Selcuk, use `reversed(originallist)` instead of `originallist[::-1]`.

```
originallist = [
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/1",
    "author": "john",
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/2",
    "author": "marry",
    "count": 19
  },
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/1",
    "author": "john",
    "count": 45
  },
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/5",
    "author": "jane",
    "count": 34
  }
]

unique_dict = {(d["title"], d["url"], d["author"]): d for d in reversed(originallist)}
newlist = list(unique_dict.values())
```

Comment: Good idea. Consider using `reversed()` to return a generator to improve the performance and reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: I found the edit interesting. How does reversed() reduce the memory footprint here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that the problem is in the fact that the `in` operator you are relying on leverages the addresses of the dictionary instances, rather than their *values*.
If you can rely on the url only to establish unicity, then you will probably be able to express your list comprehension as follows:

```py
urls = set([item["url"] for item in originallist])

[x for x in originallist if x["url"] not in urls]
```

Comment: From the question: `ignore others if title, url and author is same`. Your solution only checks for `url`.

Comment: Skip the brackets in set() and it will run faster, especially on big lists. That will make it a generator instead of first creating a list.